# Highlight duplicates only if consecutive cells Excel 2010

Tags: excel

Is there a way of only highlighting duplicate cells if they are consecutive (ie touching each other) in Excel 2010?

so if A1 says "Dog" A2 says "Dog" A3 says "Cat" and A4 says "Dog" A5 says "Cat" A6 says "Cat" it would highlight A1,A2, A5 and A6

Bit stumped here

Answer (score 0):

It would make it easier if the list of animals started at A2, then you would just highlight the range and go into Conditional Formatting | New Rule | Use a formula... and enter

```
=OR(A2=A1,A2=A3)
```

(i.e. the current cell is equal to the one above or the one below) then apply whatever formatting you want.

If you need the range to start from A1, then just add another rule for A1 only as a special case using the formula

```
=A1=A2
```

[image]